# Working React App to display public Github Repositories of a user

Tags: javascript, react.js, redux

Description of the App:-

1. A React app that shows the public Github repositories of a user.
2. The app shows an input field where we can enter a Github username and a submit button. {It provides users the feedback while getting the data in the background.}
3. The repositories are shown as a list and for each repo, the following information is displayed: Repository name, the number of stars, and forks.
4. Each Repository item in the list is made clickable. It opens the repository on Github when clicked.
5. A reset button is provided to clear the repository list
6. A username can be provided as a URL parameter while opening the application and automatically show the users repositories

Tech Stack:-

React (hooks),
Redux,
Cypress (For Testing)
Material UI,
AG-Grid

The Github README.md file has all the instructions on how to run the project.

I will appreciate it if the app can be reviewed.

What I am looking for is the following?

1. Variable, functions, Component Naming Convention.
2. Commit Messages format.
3. Good coding practices are followed or not?
4. Inputs and Feedback if code needs some optimization.
5. Directory/Folder Structure.

Please feel free to provide comments generously. I am trying to improve my coding skills and this app is a step towards that.

Disclaimer:-  Kindly use the Github link to review the code. That will give a clear idea of the directory structure, readme file, and other important aspects of the app.

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/aryan21710/GithubRepoTool.git)

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../components/Login';
import DisplayRepo from '../components/DisplayRepo';
import PageNotFound from '../components/PageNotFound';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useStyles } from '../styles/components/login.js';

const Approutes = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Box className={classes.mainContainer}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={Login} exact={true} />
                    <Route
                        path='/displayuserrepo/:uname'
                        component={DisplayRepo}
                        strict
                        exact={true}
                    />
                    <Route path='/*' component={PageNotFound} strict exact={true} />
                </Switch>
            </Box>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export default Approutes;
```